# How can I combine the Max function in REST API of LoopBack filter

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a SQL query like this

```
 SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (ID,dateTime) IN (SELECT ID, Max(dateTime) FROM myTable where ID="3645789");
```

How can I use the Max function in LoopBack RestAPI? My REST API is /api/myTable?filter[where][ID]=3645789
For the above API, I want to add Max(dateTime) which should return the row result with highest dateTime from the table.